# Two dimentional arrays (distinguishing the columns from the rows)?

Tags: java

I am a novice to java. Im trying to write a two-dementional array that writes out a lottery ticket (6 integers) 10 times

```
int[][] lottery = new int[6][10];

for (int i=0; i < lottery.length; i++)
 for (int j=0; j < lottery[0].length; j++)  
  lottery[i][j] = (int)(50.0 * Math.random());

for (int i=0; i < lottery.length; i++)
 for (int j=0; j < lottery[0].length; j++)      
 {
  /*if i < lottery.length
  System.out.print(lottery[i][j] + " ");
  else
  System.out.println(lottery[i][j]);*/
 }
```

How do I write it out as 10 rows of 6 integers

```
23 12 31 49 3 17 
9 1 22 13 36 50
.
.
.
```

Comment: You won't have much luck winning the lottery if you generate the same integer more than once for a given ticket.

Comment: Users are asked to add a "homework" tag to all questions related to homework problems.

Comment: @Adamski - i didn't ask for that differentiation. Again, im a novice. One step at a time.

Comment: @Michael - I am not a Student!  I am learning java on my own, using Ivor Horton's Beginning Java book. Im on Capter 4 (Arrays and Strings). However, i can see how you would think that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is backwards. If you want to be able to output 10 rows of 6 numbers with the nested for loops that you have, you would need the array to be `int lottery[][] = new int[10][6];`

Then to output it, you'd simply need to do:

```
for (int i=0; i < lottery.length; i++){
 for (int j=0; j < lottery[i].length; j++){
    System.out.print(lottery[i][j]+"");
    if(j < lottery[i].length -1){
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
 }
 System.out.print("\n");
}
```

The call to System.out.print will print the text without a new-line character so you can keep appending to the same line.

Comment: Thanks Chris for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0):

Java (like C), stores multidimensional arrays in [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Depending on your mindset this may seem natural or not but just remember arrays are referenced by `[row][col]`, not `[col][row]`.

Your array `int[][] lottery = new int[6][10];` is 6 rows, 10 cols each. Based on your description, I think you want 10 rows or 6 cols each or `int[][] lottery = new int[10][6];`

Then print it:

```
for (int i=0; i < lottery.length; i++) 
{
     for (int j=0; j < lottery[0].length; j++)      
     {
          if (j < (lottery[0].length+1)
          { 
              System.out.print(lottery[i][j] + " ");
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println(lottery[i][j]);
          }
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

10 rows of 6 integers:

```
int[][] lottery = new int[10][6];
```

Formatted printing:

```
for(int row=0; row<nums.length; row++) {
    for(int col=0; col<nums[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d", nums[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

[Go through the title "Format String Syntax" here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)